# Gatling:test objective seems to compile twice

Tags: scala, maven, gatling

I want to use *Gatling* for load testing from JupyterLab. I have set up everything as described on the Gatling site: I have maven, scala and gatling-maven-plugin. After setting up the pom.xml however, everytime I run the command: mvn gatling:test, I get an error stating that my simulation class "BasicSimulation" is already defined. Looks like it's being compiled twice.

I have tried to recreate the entire project. I have tried the "disable compiler" flag. I havet ried to with maven compiler as plugin and without. I have tried shifting plugin order around.

actual code i'm using, from https://gatling.io/docs/current/quickstart

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._ // 2
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class BasicSimulation extends Simulation { // 3

  val httpProtocol = http // 4
    .baseUrl("http://computer-database.gatling.io") // 5
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // 6
    .doNotTrackHeader("1")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")

  val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation") // 7
    .exec(http("request_1") // 8
      .get("/")) // 9
    .pause(5) // 10

  setUp( // 11
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)) // 12
  ).protocols(httpProtocol) // 13
}
```

I have included my pom.xml file on pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/siV43Skf

I think the problem lies there.

I expect the BasicSimulation to run correctly but instead I get that my BasicSimulation class is already defined -- even though it's one file in the whole project.

Comment: Have you tried changing name of this class or adding package name? BasicSimulation is default name for simulation generated by gatling recorder. Maybe somewhere in your project there already exist simulation with that name?

Comment: @MateuszGruszczynski I have actually renamed it as my first idea, but it didn't help - the error changed to NewName is already compiled :(
the whole project contains one file - BasicSimulation.scala

Comment: Can you confirm your project structure? All your .scala files should be under src/test/scala/somepackage
also this reference pom.xml should help: https://github.com/gatling/gatling-maven-plugin-demo/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: @VangeliszKetipisz As I said, it's all a ready project copied from Gatling site. New finding is that after restarting the pod it works once or twice and then starts to show the same error...